# How can I cache the contents of a text file in a model once per deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this text file in which I have to refer to values inside it constantly. I must compare certain values from the database against certain entries in the text file. Both datasets are very large. I do not load this text file (I'll call it the `changefile`) into the database, because doing the comparisons in the database takes way too long. And I don't put the `changefile` into a database table, because it's easier to read from a file, and I don't want to have to search for an upload a new `changefile` every time a new one is released.

What I do instead is read a bunch of records from the db into text strings, read the file into text strings, and compare those.

I have a model in which the text strings from the changefile are represented in a variable. It looks like this:

```
class Standard < ActiveRecord::Base

  def changes
    @changes ||= read_the_file_into_an_array
  end

end
```

This is good because I am only doing the file read once. However, that's once per instantiation of the `Standard` class. What I want to do is ensure that I only read the file once per `deployment`.

Outside of reading the file into some kind of ugly global variable in an initializer, what can I do to make sure I only ever read the file once after Rails boots up?

*** UPDATE ***

```
class MyObject < ParentObject

  @changes ||= get_changes

  class << self

    attr_accessor :changes, :get_changes

    def get_changes
      <read file and return array>
    end

  end

end
```

Can't get this working. Error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `get_changes' for MyObject:Class
```

I don't get it at all. Why is `get_changes` being accessed as a `local` variable?

Comment: Check out class variables. I think it's what you're looking for. This page may get you started: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: I understand how to do that with a static value like in the example, but is it possible to also use a setter for the class variable that will only fire once?

Comment: def self.changes; @@changes ||= read_the_file_into_an_array; end

Comment: It looks like I have the more complicated use case since this class is a subclass of another, and I need the subclasses to each access different files. It sounds like from the docs that @@ will set that variable for the superclass and all subclasses.

Comment: It has to do with the order I put stuff in the class.

Comment: get_changes is being called as a local variable or method because you haven't told it that it needs to be a class method. try self.class.get_changes, but be aware that where you're calling it that will be executed every time you instantiate an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it be read as part of an initializer and load it into a variable or config depending on the file context